# XSLT copy-of only child data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML data that looks like this:

```
<data>
  <old><value>1</value></old>
  <new><value>2</value></new>
</data>
```

And I'm trying to grab only data under `<new>` so the result should like this:

```
<value>2</value>
```

I'm using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">    
  <xsl:template match="new">
    <xsl:copy-of  select="node()" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the output is keeping some of the stray data from `<old>` and looking like this:

```
1
<value>2</value>
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy-of select="new/node()" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...posted this question too soon!  I needed to add an xsl template to ignore everything under old.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">    
  <xsl:template match="new">
    <xsl:copy-of  select="node()" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="old" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```